# Do I need aTransit visa for UK to Sweden even if I have a USA and Australia visa

Tags: transit, fijian-citizens

I am a Fiji national with a multiple entry schengen visa travelling to Sweden this weekend.I am travelling via Los Angeles with a USA visa and London to Sweden.
I also have a multiple entry Australian visa.

Do i need a transit visa for the 7 hour layover in London travelling on the same British Airways airlines from Los Angeles to Sweden with the visas I already have.

Comment: No you don't, and with the US visa you can even enter the UK and stay until 23:59 the next day, giving you time to visit London (although 7 hours may be a bit tight for that)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the citizens of Fiji [need a visa](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/648410/UK_Visa_requirements_Oct_2017.pdf) to enter or transit the UK landside only, so if you are not leaving an international airport, you'll be fine.

Comment: The etkt only says that I will arive in London, Heathrow on British Airways and will depart from London, Heathrow on British Airways.I am not sure if I will change terminals or whether this will involve a landside transit.